# How to read .csv files in java using scanner with multiple commas and double quotes

Tags: java, design-patterns, java.util.scanner

I have a .csv file which has comma as well as double quotes separated values.

Now i want to parse comma separated values and when there are values in double quotes i want scanner to use double quotes as delimiter.

Example Line to parse:

123,student,"exam notification", "pattern should be same,validated,proper"

now i want to parse it like :

```
123  //comma seperated
student
exam notification   //when "" it should be double quote separated
pattern should be same,validated,proper  //ignore , comma in double quotes
```

Code i have tried:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(",|\"");
```

So that it can use both , and "" it does well but in between it prints blank line where **,"** strikes and also cant ignore commas between double quotes.

Any idea how to sort it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not reinvent the wheel...try Super CVS here

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html

Regards

Comment: I wanted to edit CVS to CSV. But edits are only allowed when more than 6 characters change. Can you - the initiator - edit it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSV parser like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to take care of things like commas in quoted elements, values that span multiple lines etc. automatically. You can use the library to serialize your text back as CSV as well.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));

String [] nextLine;
// prints the following for the line in your question
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(nextLine[0]); // 123
    System.out.println(nextLine[1]); // student
    System.out.println(nextLine[2]); // exam notification
    System.out.println(nextLine[3]); // pattern should be same,validated,proper
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to achieve what you want to do,

1.) Use an existing library that supports parsing CSV's like Ravi Thapliyal and Oibaf it suggested.

2.) You may provide your method

```
         a). if every line in your CSV have a uniform format like : 
            line 1 :  123,student,"exam notif","word , word , word"
            line 2 : 45345,not student,"no exam notif","word,word,word"
   you can say like 

        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        //split it using double quotes first
        temp = line.split("\"");
        //then just remove commas outside the double quoted objects
        for(int x = 0; x<temp.length; x++){
            if(temp[x].startsWith(",")) {temp[x] = temp[x].substring(1,temp[x].length()); }
            if(temp[x].endsWith(",")) {temp[x] = temp[x].substring(0,temp[x].length()-1); }
        }
```

As far as this programmer is concerned , Java does not have any existing class,method for multiple delimiters, but there are some libraries that can make life easier for you
,  but you are always given an option to provide your own method . Gud luck